# Unable to line up these <TD> rows

Tags: html, css

I have a table I am using for an image and some text on a footer (using Avada on WordPress). For the life of me I am unable to line these up. Would anybody be able to provide some guidance?

Code is below as well link to codepen:

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" width="100%">
      <img valign="bottom" align="center" src="https://test.seescan.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Underground_Evolved_Horizontal-6.png" alt="Underground_Evolved_Footer" width="500px" height="400px" />
    </td>
    <td width="100%">
      <p style="color: #999999; line-height:8px;" align="center">Copyright ©
        <script>
          document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
        </script> SeeScan. All rights reserved.</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your codepen is empty

Comment: What exactly do you mean "line up"? Line up horizontally at the top? middle? bottom? Vertically so they meet in the middle? We can't help you fix it if we don't know what  you want to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your image has more white space on one side of it than on the other. This makes it so you cannot center it easily (you could use left/right attribute, but this will be finicky on different sized screens). I would recommend cropping it so that it is centered by default.

Below I added a row so that the copyright is centered below the image. I also added a black background and white border to the image so that you can see the image has more white space on the right side.

```css
/* made background black to see white picture */
table {
  background-color:black;
}

img {
  border:solid 1px white;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="center" width="100%">
<img valign="bottom" align="center" src="https://test.seescan.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Underground_Evolved_Horizontal-6.png" alt="Underground_Evolved_Footer" width="500" />
</td>
  <tr>
<td align="center" width="100%">
<p style="color: #999999; line-height:8px;" align="center">Copyright ©  <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> SeeScan. All rights reserved.</p>
</td>
    </tr>
</tr>
</table>
```